# how to retrieve JSON object from the JSON array

Tags: java, json

I am having the below JSON. Inside this JSON I am having "ticketDetails" as JSON array. From this array I want to retrieve the value of ticketPrice inside the json object "amount". How can I do that?

```
{
    "ticketDetails": [{
        "seq": 1,
        "qty": 2,
        "amount": {
            "ticketPrice": 120,
            "bookingFee": 50
        },
        "session": {
            "id": 1001,
            "date": "2013, 9, 15",
            "time": "1300"
        },
        "venue": {
            "id": "MTRG",
            "name": "Adlabs Manipur",
            "companyCode": "ADLB"
        },
        "event": {
            "id": "ET00000001123",
            "name": "Chennai Express",
            "producerCode": "YRF"
        },
        "category": {
            "ttypeCode": "00012",
            "areaCatCode": "2414",
            "type": "Gold",
            "price": 270
        }
    }]
}
```

Any suggestion will helpful...

Comment: Which programming language do you use? JavaScript? By the way, the ``enter code here`` makes your JSON invalid.

Comment: Is there a reason ticketDetails is an array? If you want an extremely modular, object oriented solution, you could check out the [GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) library. It may be overkill, but it's worth a quick gander. You would essentially deserialize the json into its respective java objects and then use getters to retrieve the data you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this code:

```
JsonObject transactiondata = (JsonObject)Offer.get("transData");
JsonObject ticketdata = (JsonObject)transactiondata.get("tickets");
JsonObject offerData = (JsonObject)Offer.get("offerData");
JsonObject offerData1 = (JsonObject)offerData.get("offerconfig");

JsonArray jsonarr= (JsonArray)ticketdata.get("ticketDetails");

double ticketPrice = Double.parseDouble(jsonarr.get(0).getAsJsonObject().get("amount").getAsJsonObject().get("ticketPrice").getAsString());
System.out.println("ticketPrice:"+ticketPrice);
```

Answer (score 2):

Below is the sample code for retrieving the `ticketPrice` from the given JSONObject:

```
JSONObject objData = (JSONObject)JSONSerializer.toJSON(data);
JSONArray objTicketDetailsJsonArr = objData.getJSONArray("ticketDetails");
for(int nSize=0; nSize < objTicketDetailsJsonArr.size(); nSize++){
    String ticketPrice = "";
    ticketPrice = objTicketDetailsJsonArr.getString("ticketPrice");
}
```

Below are the imports for the above code:

```
import net.sf.json.JSONArray;
import net.sf.json.JSONObject;
import net.sf.json.JSONSerializer;
```

source of JAR: http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

you store your data within a variable

```
  data = {...}
```

then you access it this way:

```
data.ticketDetails[0].amount.ticketPrice
```

if the ticketDetails have more than one element

you can loop over the ticketDetails array and store all the ticketPrice values within an other array, ticketPriceArray

the following would work fine in JavaScript:

```
var ticketPriceArray = data.ticketDetails.map(function(k){
 return k.amount.ticketPrice;
});
```

if you are using another programming language a general loop would work fine also

```
for ( i; i< ticketDetails.length ; i++){
    ticketPriceArray[i] = data.ticketDetails.amount.ticketPrice[i];
}
```

For Java check this tutorial: 
http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/257-how-to-parse-json-in-java/